# Micronaut function application with JPA

Tags: kotlin, jpa, micronaut

I'm trying to create a Micronaut function application with JPA support.

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.library") version "1.2.0"
}

version = "1.0.0"
group = "dk.fitfit"

val kotlinVersion = project.properties["kotlinVersion"]

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("dk.fitfit.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.8")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")

    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.6.0")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.7")

}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as I add JPA annotations to my Book class I get an exception

Book.kt

```
@Introspected
@Entity
class Book {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    val id: Long = 0
    var name: String? = null
}
```

Exception

```
Bean definition [io.micronaut.test.transaction.TestTransactionInterceptorListener] could not be loaded: Failed to inject value for parameter [rollback] of class: io.micronaut.test.transaction.TestTransactionInterceptorListener

Message: Error resolving property value [micronaut.test.rollback]. Property doesn't exist
Path Taken: new TestTransactionInterceptorListener(TestTransactionInterceptor interceptor,[boolean rollback])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.test.transaction.TestTransactionInterceptorListener] could not be loaded: Failed to inject value for parameter [rollback] of class: io.micronaut.test.transaction.TestTransactionInterceptorListener

Message: Error resolving property value [micronaut.test.rollback]. Property doesn't exist
Path Taken: new TestTransactionInterceptorListener(TestTransactionInterceptor interceptor,[boolean rollback])
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1549)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:220)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2780)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:233)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:166)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.startEnvironment(AbstractExecutor.java:125)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.buildApplicationContext(MicronautRequestHandler.java:149)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.<init>(MicronautRequestHandler.java:59)
    at dk.fitfit.BookRequestHandler.<init>(BookRequestHandler.kt:7)
    at dk.fitfit.BookRequestHandlerTest.testHandler(BookRequestHandlerTest.kt:9)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [rollback] of class: io.micronaut.test.transaction.TestTransactionInterceptorListener
```

My test

```
@MicronautTest
class BookRequestHandlerTest {
    @Test
    fun testHandler() {
        val bookRequestHandler = BookRequestHandler()
        val book = Book()
        book.name = "Hello from Lambda through Api Gateway!"

        val bookSaved = bookRequestHandler.execute(book).body
        Assertions.assertNotNull(bookSaved)
//        Assertions.assertEquals(book.name, bookSaved.name)
//        Assertions.assertNotNull(bookSaved.isbn)

        bookRequestHandler.applicationContext.close()
    }
}
```

Request handler

```
@Introspected
class BookRequestHandler : MicronautRequestHandler<Book?, ValidApiGatewayResponse<BookSaved>>() {
    override fun execute(input: Book?): ValidApiGatewayResponse<BookSaved> {
        val bookSaved = BookSaved("Hello from Lambda through Api Gateway!", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        return ValidApiGatewayResponse(bookSaved)
    }
}
```

Complete project: https://github.com/tonsV2/mn-lambda

Comment: Can you show `BookRequestHandler`?

Comment: I've updated the question but the error occurs as soon as I create an entity. I don't even have to use it anywhere.

Comment: `"...but the error occurs as soon as I create an entity"` - Your stacktrack indicates otherwise.  The stacktrace seems to suggest that the error is happening at `BookRequestHandler` construction time.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I've updated the question with a link to the complete project

Comment: When I run that test it passes.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Also if you remove the "rollback: false" from application.yml ?

Comment: No.  If `rollback: false` is removed then an exception is thrown while constructing the `BookRequestHandler` and the code that creates the `Book` is never executed. I don't see any scenarios in your app where the creation of the entity causes a problem.

Comment: If I remove `rollback: false` and the entity the exception goes away

Comment: "If I remove rollback: false and the entity the exception goes away" - That doesn't happen for me.  If I remove `rollback: false` the `BookRequestHandler` construction leads to the exception.  I see the exception mentioned in the question which is coming from the `BookRequestHandler` constructor (dk.fitfit.BookRequestHandler.<init>(BookRequestHandler.kt:7).  The exception you posted in the question and the exception I am seeing locally are coming from the `BookRequestHandler` constructor, not the `Book` constructor.

Comment: Correction.  My last comment is *incorrect*.  If I remove `rollback: true`, then the thing I described above happens.  I didn't mean removing 'rollback: false`.  I meant `rollback: true`.  I am sorry for any confusion caused there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was add the following to my application.yml

```
micronaut:
  test:
    rollback: false
```

Comment: that seems wrong. how does your test look like? what MicronautTest annotation did you use? You should not need to add this configuration to your application.yml

Comment: I was a bit baffled that it wasn't set by default. So I have actually been wondering if this was the right way. I've updated the question with my test. It's pretty much the default generated test.

Comment: @saw303 I've updated the question with a link to the complete project